# How to create an new instance of an Object in React?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, reactjs

Obviously in normal JS I can do this

```
var Card = function(rank, suit){
    this.rank = rank; 
    this.suit = suit
  }

var cardOne = new Card('3', 'H');

cardOne // Card {rank: "3", suit: "H"}
```

So how would I do that in react and ES6 land?

I have tried something like this:

```
class ReactApp extends React.Component{

  Card = (rank, suit) => {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  };

  createCard = () => {
    let CardObj = {};
    let card = new this.Card('3', 'Hearts');
    console.log(card);
  };

}
```

(not showing render method for now)

but how can I get that to log the correct thing in react?
how are functions treated inside React? (key value pairs?) and how do i define objects etc?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? You can just define a function and call it `Card`, then in your `ReactApp` class instantiate it like you were doing before `new Card(rank, suit)`.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about a component? Create a component called `Card`, just as you did with `ReactApp`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for Card model you can create a new ES6 class for that

```
export class Card {
  constructor(rank, suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}
```

After this, you can import that model into react component as

```
import {Card} from './card'
```

Answer (score 11):

A little bit late, but still...

Since React v16.8 when hooks were introduced it's been suggested to use functional components over class ones.

```
const Card = function(rank, suit) {
    const rank = rank;
    const suit = suit;
    return { rank, suit };
};

const cardOne = Card("3", "H");

cardOne; // {rank: "3", suit: "H"}
cardOne.rank; // "3"
cardOne.suit; // "H"
```

But that is a little old-styled. Most elegant way to do this in one line of code using arrow function:

```
const Card = (rank, suit) => { return { rank: rank, suit: suit } }
```

That's all. Now you can assign your variables.

```
const cardOne = Card('3', 'H')

cardOne // {rank: "3", suit: "H"}
cardOne.rank // "3"
cardOne.suit // "H"
```

You can also add `export` in front of your constant to make it importable from anywhere:

```
// components.js
export const Card = (rank, suit) => { return { rank: rank, suit: suit } }


// App.js
import { Card } from './components'

const cardTwo = Card('2', 'F')
cardTwo // {rank: "2", suit: "F"}
cardTwo.rank // "2"
cardTwo.suit // "F"
```

Also you should better use `const` and `let` for declaring variables instead of `var` because of hoisting. [Here](https://evertpot.com/javascript-let-const/) is a good article explaining why.

Comment: is there an advantage to using this "functional" approach than the "class" approach answer provided by @jagadish

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about defining classes that just contain data, then it's just an ES6 issue, not a React specific one. The simple answer is to declare the `Card` class separately from your component, e. g.

```
class Card {
  constructor(rank, suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}

class ReactApp extends React.Component{ ... }
```

Another way to solve this problem is to simply use ES5 (aka "normal javascript"), since I assume that you're more familiar with it. Using React does not force you to use ES6.

Here's a list of useful articles about ES6: https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/es6-in-depth/

And here's information about using ES5 in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html